# Jquery toolstrip deactivate when menu open

Tags: javascript, jquery, toolstrip

I am using jquery toolstrip plugin.I need to disable it when my sidebar menu is opened. Following codes are my menu with li tags.

```
<div class="sidebar-wrapper" id="sidebar-wrapper">
<ul>
  <li class="navigation-header">
    <a href="#" class="btn btnMenu">
        Button
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="tooltipster" title="Redakte paneli"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="tooltipster" title="Axtaris"></a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

My javascript codes:

```
$('.btnMenu').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#sidebar-wrapper").hasClass("closeMenu")) {
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").animate({ width: "240px" });
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").removeClass("closeMenu").addClass("openMenu");
        $(".content-wrapper").animate({ left: "280px" });

   }
}
```

Comment: Please make a snippet of add more relevant markup

Comment: Tried changing `class="sidebar-wrapper"` to `class="sidebar-wrapper closeMenu"` ?  or `if ($("#sidebar-wrapper").hasClass("closeMenu")) {` to `if ($("#sidebar-wrapper").hasClass("closeMenu") || $("#sidebar-wrapper:not(.openMenu)")) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with using following code of jquery toolstriper :

```
$(".tooltipster").tooltipster('disable');
```